# Calculating the amount of seconds passed since firebase server timestamp?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a website that allows users to post stuff, and I want to add a "trending" section. How would I go about calculating the amount of seconds passed since the post was made?

I have a firebase server timestamp stored for each post:

```
topic_obj.time = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP ;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How does the timestamp look like? Can you add an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to calculate time differences in Javascript:

firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP will be the number of milliseconds since Unix epoch, see [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue)

```
let timeStamp = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
let endTime = moment();
let startTime = moment(timeStamp);

var duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
var durationSeconds = duration.asSeconds();
console.log('Duration (seconds): ', durationSeconds);
```

Once can also just subtract:

```
let timeStamp = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
let now = new Date().getTime();

let differenceSeconds = (now - timeStamp)/1000;
```